# Getting SEGFAULT when trying to delete node from a binary search tree

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, tree

I am implementing a binary search tree in C. The code below works fine, except that I get a SEGFAULT when I try to delete a subtree from my tree:

**Source code:**

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node * right, * left;
};

void insert(node ** tree, int val)
{
    node *temp = NULL;
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        temp->data = val;
        *tree = temp;
        return;
    }

    if(val < (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->left, val);
    }
    else if(val > (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->right, val);
    }

}

void print_preorder(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {
        printf("%d\n",tree->data);
        print_preorder(tree->left);
        print_preorder(tree->right);
    }

}

void print_inorder(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {
        print_inorder(tree->left);
        printf("%d\n",tree->data);
        print_inorder(tree->right);
    }
}

void print_postorder(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {
        print_postorder(tree->left);
        print_postorder(tree->right);
        printf("%d\n",tree->data);
    }
}

 void deltree(struct node* node)
{
    if (node == NULL) return;

    struct node *r = node->right;

    deltree(node->left);
    free(node);
    deltree(r);
}

node* search(node ** tree, int val)
{
    if(!(*tree))
        return NULL;

    if(val < (*tree)->data)
    {
        return search(&((*tree)->left), val);
    }
    else if(val > (*tree)->data)
    {
        return search(&((*tree)->right), val);
    }
    else if(val == (*tree)->data)
    {
        return *tree;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void _deleteTree(struct node* node)
{
    if (node == NULL) return;

    _deleteTree(node->left);
    _deleteTree(node->right);

    printf("\nDeleting node: %d", node->data);
    free(node);
}

void deleteTree(struct node** node_ref)
{
  _deleteTree(*node_ref);
  *node_ref = NULL;
}


int  main()
{
    node *root;
    node *tmp;
    node *tmp1;

    root = NULL;
    insert(&root, 9);
    insert(&root, 4);
    insert(&root, 15);
    insert(&root, 6);
    insert(&root, 12);
    insert(&root, 17);
    insert(&root, 2);

    printf("\nPrinting tree before deletion...\n");
    print_postorder(root);

    tmp1 = search(&root, 15);

    printf("Deleting subtree...\n");
    deleteTree(&tmp1);

    printf("\nPrinting tree after deletion...\n");
    print_postorder(root);
}
```

**Output:**

```
Printing tree before deletion...
2
6
4
12
17
15
9

Deleting subtree...

Deleting node: 12
Deleting node: 17
Deleting node: 15
Printing tree after deletion...
2
6
4
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Please note that I want to delete *subtree* from the whole tree (though my code should work for the whole tree as well).

Comment: the parent of the node references a deleted node, after you have deleted the node. This is why you get a segfault, set the parents right or left to null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call `deleteTree` with the argument `&tmp1`, the `deleteTree` function sets `tmp1` to point to `NULL`. However, this has no effect on the corresponding pointer in the actual tree (that is, the `left` or `right` pointer of a node in the tree that points to the node containing the value 15). That pointer still points to the now-deleted node.

Change search as follows:

```
node** search(node ** tree, int val)
{
    if(!(*tree))
        return NULL;

    if(val < (*tree)->data)
    {
        return search(&((*tree)->left), val);
    }
    else if(val > (*tree)->data)
    {
        return search(&((*tree)->right), val);
    }
    else if(val == (*tree)->data)
    {
        return tree;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

and the main function as follows:

```
node** tmp1;
...
printf("Deleting subtree...\n");
deleteTree(tmp1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you got SEGFAULT is that you point to an address which make no sense . After you free the node that points to 15 , you set tmp1 to NULL .Everything you done until now is right except that you didn't set the parent's right child pointer to NULL either ,which now still point to the original address . But the address is meaningless now .On my computer ,it didn't cause SEGFAULT ,while it prints out some random numbers .